# Unknown mathematical error in sympy equation (python)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

I am attempting to plot the functions j0,j1 & j10 in the range r(0,20) by converting them to numpy format using lambdify. I used the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym
from ipywidgets.widgets import interact
sym.init_printing(use_latex="mathjax")
x, y, z, t = sym.symbols('x y z t')    

r = sym.symbols("r", positive=True)
j0 = (sym.diff(((sym.cos(sym.sqrt(r**2-2*r*t)))/r),t)).subs({t:0})
j1 = (sym.diff(((sym.cos(sym.sqrt(r**2-2*r*t)))/r),t,2)).subs({t:0})
j10 = (sym.diff(((sym.cos(sym.sqrt(r**2-2*r*t)))/r),t,11)).subs({t:0})

k = sym.lambdify(r,j0)
l = sym.lambdify(r,j1)
m = sym.lambdify(r,j10)
myr = np.linspace(0,20,1000)
plt.plot(myr,k(myr),label="$j_{0}(r)$")
plt.plot(myr,l(myr),label="$j_{1}(r)$")
plt.plot(myr,m(myr),label="$j_{10}(r)$")
plt.ylim(-1,1)
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("r")
plt.ylabel("$j_{n}(r)$")
```

I got this output:

[image]

Which seems at least partially correct, however I also got this error message which I've never seen before:

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py:1:                     RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  """
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py:1:   RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  """
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py:1:   RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  """
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  """
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  """
```

I suspect this has something to do with using .subs({t:0}) however after much revising and reworking the code I find I'm unable to get the formulas I want for j0, j1 and j10 without using .subs. I think this error has a knock-on effect as I get an error quoting "incorrect syntax" when I try to substitute the formula for j10 into the following equation (which is supposed to go to 0):

```
(r**2)*sym.diff(m,r,2) + (2*r)*sym.diff(m,r) + (r**2 - 10*(10+1))*m
```

Where m is the numpy version of j10.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have a function of the type `f(r)/r` and you compute that function for `r=0` (see the line with the `np.linspace`), so I'm guessing that this is where your problems come from. Can you do a `print(k(myr))` before you plot (maybe with a few less values)?

Comment: Sorry but what's the exact purpose of doing that? I just get a list of values starting with the undefined one for r=0. I'm wondering how to go about avoiding this error, or whether it can be avoided at all given the equations.

Comment: The idea of the print command was to separate the calculations from the visualisation to better isolate the problem, but you are right, it was probably unnecessary because one can see that already from the error message. See my answer for a possible workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by a division by zero, which is numerically hard to deal with, even though the limit of `r->0` may be finite. I would have two (slightly different) solutions to the problem.

1) Replace the problematic point with the mathematical exact result. In your example this would mean something along the lines (`limit` is the exact solution of the function for `r->0` that you derive first on paper) :

```
myr = np.linspace(0,20,1000)
k_noerror = np.concatenate([[limit], k(myr[1:])])
plt.plot(myr,k_noerror,label="$j_{0}(r)$")
```

2) If you cannot calculate the limit yourself, you may be able to fix the problem by replacing your zero with a very small value, i.e.:

```
myr = np.linspace(0,20,1000)
myr[0] = 1e-3
plt.plot(myr,k(myr),label="$j_{0}(r)$")
```

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot more sense. I'm not really sure what the expectation for the answer is (this is an assignment for college) so I'll try one of these workarounds and give some explanation as to why.